# Linq on windows phone

Tags: linq, windows-phone-7, linq-to-objects

It appears I can use the .Where, .First, etc linq expressions in a Windows Phone 7 class library, but not Contains or FindIndex.   Are they really not available at all, or is there something else I need to include to access them?

Comment: `FindIndex` exists on `List` and `Array` but not `IEnumerable`.  `Contains` should be there for you.  What does your code look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Contains already exists in WP7

```
System.Linq.Enumerable.Contains
```

For FindIndex, a work arround like this should be sufficient

```
var index = YourList.IndexOf(YourList.FirstOrDefault(selector));
```

Answer (score 4):

You should be able to use `Contains`, but `FindIndex` isn't part of LINQ - it's a method on `List<T>` normally. However, it's not part of [`List<T>` in Silverlight](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s6hkc2c4%28v=VS.95%29.aspx).

If you're having trouble with `Contains`, please show a piece of code which is failing.

Answer (score 0):

For `FindIndex`, you can create the method in a class helper:

```
public static int FindIndex<TSource>(this List<TSource> list, Func<TSource, bool> match)
{
    return list.IndexOf(list.FirstOrDefault(match));
}
```

Then it will work normally.